# Python kivy: выводится пустой экран

Tags: python, kivy

Я новичок в kivy python. Я решил воспользоваться kivy, но в результате ничего не появляется, а выводиться только пустой экран. Что я делаю неправильно?

Код:

Tests.py

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class TestApp(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TestApp()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
Button:
    text: 'Hello from test.kv'
```

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю то Test.py и test.kv у вас никак не связаны

Comment: @Farodin Как его можно связать?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то объявляете кнопку вы в питон файле а потом в файле .kv дабавляете для неё стиль и тд просто в файле .kv называете кнопку также как и в питон файле

Answer (score 0):

Нужно импортировать Builder:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
```

Затем нужно написать:

```
Builder.load_file("Имя файла.kv").
```